# Ubuntu runs terribly slow on my desktop

Tags: drivers, video, performance

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 partition on my secondary SSD, while the bootloader and windows 7 partition are one another SSD. My desktop is a gaming rig running an Intel i5 3570k, ati Radeon HD 7870 OC, 8gb of DDR3 RAM, Gigabyte Z77x-up5-th, etc. I ran the software updater and checked the video card drivers and tried different ones but no luck. If anyone could help me that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening.  Thanks!